# New list every While loop

Tags: python, list, random, while-loop

I want to create two lists ("lstA", "lstB") each comprised of 50 random numbers. I then want to compare the two lists and any overlap that is present I want put into a third list ("lstOvrlp"). I then would like to take the length of that third list and place it into a fourth list ("lstC").

Next I want that basic program to loop  10 times (I'll add user input for this part later).

This is the code I have so far:

```
    def main():

        import random

        lstA = []
        lstB = []
        lstC = []



        lstA = random.sample(range(1, 101), 50)
        lstB = random.sample(range(1, 101), 50)

        lstOvrlp = set(lstA) & set(lstB)

        while len(lstC) <= 10:
            print("This is list A:", lstA)
            print("\n")
            print("This is list B:", lstB)
            print("\n")
            print("This is the overlap between the two lists:", lstOvrlp)

            numinC = len(lstOvrlp)
            print("Number in common: ", numinC)
            print("\n")

            lstC.append(numinC)
            print(lstC)



    main()
```

The issue is that rather than spitting out random numbers each time through the loop the program just re-uses the same numbers over and over again resulting in the same overlap numbers and consequently the same lengths in "lstC". Perhaps there is some other function in Random that I just don't know about, but I can't find it.

I'd like there to be a new batch of numbers in "lstA" and "lstB" each time the program loops so that "lstC" ends up with varied entries. I'm trying to get some practice working with data and eventually I'll be running some simple statistics analysis on this information such as averages and what not.

While I can't point out the errors that are here, I can guarantee there are plenty of them so please be patient.

Thanks

Comment: You should put the `random.sample` generation **within** the `while` loop. Otherwise you generate them (one time) and *then* loop, but not generating random samples again

Comment: How did you expect them to change if you don't change them?

Comment: you should generate those samples - lstA and lstB inside the loop :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A program in Python runs sequentially. That is, when it sees an assignment, it performs that assignment and then leaves it. If you make an assignment *before* a loop, then the value will be the same at every iteration of that loop. If you make an assignment *inside* a loop, it will change at each iteration. I believe what you want is the latter.

Rather than

```
lstA = random.sample(range(1, 101), 50)
lstB = random.sample(range(1, 101), 50)
lstOvrlp = set(lstA) & set(lstB)
while len(lstC) <= 10:
    ...
```

consider

```
while len(lstC) <= 10:
    lstA = random.sample(range(1, 101), 50)
    lstB = random.sample(range(1, 101), 50)
    lstOvrlp = set(lstA) & set(lstB)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a generator and `random.randint` then compare the lists as sets to get the intersection.

```
from random import randint


def random_list():
    for _ in range(50):
        yield randint(1, 101)


list_c = []

for _ in range(10):
    list_a = list(random_list())
    list_b = list(random_list())
    print('list_a: {}'.format(list_a))
    print('list_b: {}'.format(list_b))

    # This is actually called an intersection, not an overlap.
    list_intersect = set(list_a) & set(list_b)
    print('list_overlap: {}'.format(list_intersect))

    list_c.append(len(list_intersect))

print(list_c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close! You simply needed to move your `lstA = random.sample(range(1, 101), 50)` and `lstB = random.sample(range(1, 101), 50)` to inside the while loop so they'd be assigned new numbers. Try this.

```
import random
def main():


    while len(lstC) <= 10:
        lstA = random.sample(range(1, 101), 50)
        lstB = random.sample(range(1, 101), 50)

        lstOvrlp = set(lstA) & set(lstB)
        print("This is list A:", lstA)
        print("\n")
        print("This is list B:", lstB)
        print("\n")
        print("This is the overlap between the two lists:", lstOvrlp)

        numinC = len(lstOvrlp)
        print("Number in common: ", numinC)
        print("\n")

        lstC.append(numinC)
        print(lstC)



main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that in your `while` loop you aren't changing `lstA`, `lstB`, or `lstC`. Instead, try the following:

```
def main():

    import random

    lstA = []
    lstB = []
    lstC = []

    while len(lstC) <= 10:
        lstA = random.sample(range(1, 101), 50)
        lstB = random.sample(range(1, 101), 50)

        lstOvrlp = set(lstA) & set(lstB)
        print("This is list A:", lstA)
        print("\n")
        print("This is list B:", lstB)
        print("\n")
        print("This is the overlap between the two lists:", lstOvrlp)

        numinC = len(lstOvrlp)
        print("Number in common: ", numinC)
        print("\n")

        lstC.append(numinC)
        print(lstC)


main()
```